# How to put an object list into an asp:literal?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class and have added objects to a list, then binded the list to a checkboxlist. When the user checks the list, the answer goes into a new list and put in a session, then redirected to a new page. On the new page I want the result in an asp:Literal. But Im not sure how to do that.

The class:

```
public class Frukter

{
    public string Navn { get; set; }
    public string Farge { get; set; }
    public string BildeSrc { get; set; }


    public Frukter(string navn, string farge, string bildeSrc)
    {
        Navn = navn;
        Farge = farge;
        BildeSrc = bildeSrc;
    }

}
```

---

First page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Frukter> frukt = new List<Frukter>();
        frukt.Add(new Frukter("Appelsin", "Oransj", "~/Appelsin.jpg"));
        frukt.Add(new Frukter("Banan", "Gul", "~/Banan.jpg" ));
        frukt.Add(new Frukter("Eple", "Rød", "~/Eple.jpg" ));



        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {


            chklst.DataSource = frukt;
            chklst.DataTextField = "Navn";

            chklst.DataBind();
        }

 protected void Resultat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
        List<object> ChkListe = new List<object>();


        foreach (ListItem item in chklst.Items)
        {
            if(item.Selected)

                // If the item is selected, add the value to the list.
                ChkListe.Add(item);
        }

        Session["selectedChkList"] = ChkListe;
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx", false);
    }  
}
```

---

Second page where I take the list out of session, but not sure how to get it into the asp:literal.

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<object> ResultatList = new List<object>();
            if (Session["selectedChkList"] != null) 
            {
                ResultatList = (List<object>)Session["selectedStrList"]; 

                ResultatLliteral.Text = String.Format("<p>{0} {1}</p> <img src ={3} />", Frukter.Navn, Frukter.farge, Frukter.BildeSrc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information, why are you using a literal and what exactly are you trying to pass to the other page through that session?

Comment: Its an assignment and one of the criteria is show the output in an asp:literal. the class is a fruit class. And the list is name of the fruit, colour of the fruit and an image of the fruit. I want the checkbox to only show the name, but on the next page I want to show name, colour and image of the chosen fruits.

Comment: So you want to take the user selection and output the other information on another page?

Comment: yes, thats right.

Comment: Can you not simply store their fruit choice in the session and do (Frukter)Session["..."] and then use that?

Comment: without making a new list? how do I do that? Sorry Im still a beginner in C#.

Comment: You don’t need the whole list, simply the choice the user made.  So store the fruit object like I did above.  Likely the exercise is to use session, query string (rebuild from an id), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some critique on your code and some different approaches, not sure what your assignment is but I'll provide feedback that may be beneficial for your course.

```
public class Fruit
{
     public Fruit(string name, string color, string image)
     {
         Name = name;
         Color = color;
         Image = image;
     }

     public string Name { get; }
     public string Color { get; }
     public string Image { get; }
}
```

You defined a Constructor that will always set a value upon creation, so unless you intend to modify the object after the fact you can set your properties to read only.

Personally I would use a database or another way to persist my data, but for your example you should be able to do the following:

```
var fruits = new List<Fruit>() 
{
     new Fruit("Apple", "Red", "..."),
     new Fruit("Grapefuit", "Yellow", "...")
};

// Grab the selected checkbox in the checkbox list item (You'll have to see if a collection is returned or not)
var selectedFruit = chkLFruit.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);

// Take selected item and pass full object into session.
var filter = fruits.Where(fruit => selectedFruit.Select(t => t.Text).FirstOrDefault(x => String.Compare(x, fruit.Name, true) == 0);

// Create Session
HttpContext.Session["FruitSelection"] = filter;
```

On your other page before you attempt to use simply do the following:

```
var selectedFruits = (List<Fruit>)HttpContext.Session["FruitSelection"];
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand it a little bit better now! But when I type the "Var filter = fruits.Where (fruit=> fruit.Name == selectedFruit.Select (t=> t.Text))" I  get this message: Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'IEnumerable string'. The message refers to var selectedFruit.

Comment: So I tried to make selected.Fruit to a list<T>, but that didnt work. And tried som other things that didnt work. I tried to take away .Name in fruit.Name and no error message appears. Is this wrong?:
`
         var selectedFruit = chklst.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
        var filter = frukt.Where(frukter => frukt == selectedFruit.Select(t => t.Text));
`

Comment: I also get an error on my asp:literal:
Also I get an error on my asp:literal:

````
ResultatLliteral.Text = string.Format("<p>{0} {1}</p> <img src={3} />", selectedFruits.Navn, selectedFruits.Farge, selectedFruits.BildeSrc);
````
It says: List<Fruits> does not contain a definition for Name, Colour and ImageUrl.
I dont understand what Im doing wrong. And I cant any relevant information about asp:literal on the internet. Seems like the label is more popular to use.

Comment: I modified the filter to in essence match the selected text item name to the name of the fruit.  You should not be casting to a `List<T>` you have no reason to use a generic, generics are for a method to perform the same function on multiple types without the type being present to the method until you use it elsewhere.